# jQuery isn't working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to make it where users can load their content in real time. The jQuery works perfect in Chrome and Firefox, but isn't working in any version IE. Any suggestions?

```
$(function () {
    var refreshContent = 0;
    $('#userDiv') .mouseover (function () {
        refreshContent = setInterval(function () {
            $.get("../pages/content/myContent.php", function(results) {
                $('#myContent') .html (results);
            });
            clearInterval(refreshContent);
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('#userDiv') .mouseout (function () {
        clearInterval(refreshContent);
    });
});
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Nothing stands out to me.

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces before jQuery methods. IE  $('#myContent') .html().. ?

Comment: You should probably be using setTimeout instead of setInterval.  setTimeout schedules code to be run only once, which seem to be what you want, as you're clearing the interval the very first time it runs.

Comment: Elaborate on "isn't working for any version of IE". What isn't working, what is it not doing, what versions of IE have you tried.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ttByB/ - the events work fine in IE.

Comment: I'm using IE 9 and for older versions I'm using Compatibility View which is IE 7 I believe. In Firefox & Chrome the div loads perfectly with no issues and in IE nothing happens. I'm not getting any errors, data isn't disappearing or appearing. The page is unchanged.

Comment: you should be using mouseenter and mouseleave, over and out will trigger for every child element too.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using setinterval() at all? It doesn't make sense to me. Get rid of the mouseout event and the refreshContent variable. Use setTimeout() instead, it should work fine.

My guess is that it doesn't work in IE because the clearInterval() is being called before the $.get() even fires.